# Hybrid Connection Manager doesn't connect

Tags: azure, connection, hybrid

Been trying unsuccessfully to make the [Hybrid Connection Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server) work, it's my first hands-on experience:

[image: Hybrid Connection Manager - Not Connected]

On Azure portal:

[image: Hybrid Connection Manager - Azure Portal]

I've installed Hybrid Connection Manager on my laptop (using local admin account, Win 7 Enterprise) and also used it as on-premise endpoint for a MS SQL Express instance. [psPing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psping.aspx) (great toolset by [Mark Russinovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Russinovich)) shows connectivity on port 1433 and I can connect through SSMS without any issue.

I tried this in a workshop today and one of the trainers was able to get connected when using the same network connection, but a laptop from his organization.

Any ideas on what to try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the operating system. It seems that **Windows Server 2012 or later** is a prerequisite.

Thanks to DrewB and Rtm9018 for their comments in the thread at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections:
[image: Windows Server 2012 minimum needed]

Comment: Make sure to enable websockets on your Windows Server 2012 (or later) from your "Add Roles and Features Wizard" under Web Server (IIS) => Web Server => Application Development => WebSocket Protocol