# Azure Hybrid Connection status shows "Not Connected"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've got an Azure Hybrid Application [On-Premise SQL DB & Azure WebApp].I've created an Azure Hybrid connection manager with endpoint w.r.to my On-premise DB in Windows10 machine. The Status of my hybrid connected shows **Not Connected**

Any help on this would be of great help[image: Hybrid Connection Status]

I remember Azure Hybrid connection is configured with Service Bus. I'm not sure but seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823422/azure-hybrid-connection-manager-does-not-work) that Listener should be enabled. Its first time, i'm experimenting, kindly suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not sure but seen here that Listener should be enabled.

Yes, the Listener could be enabled.

I add a hybrid connection and the status is also Not connected.

You could follow my steps.

1.Download connection manager and install it.

[image]

2.Enter Manually - enter your connection string in your hybrid connection properties - Add

Then you can see the status is Connected on Hybrid Manager and Azure Portal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/includes/app-service-hybrid-connections-manager-install.md).

Comment: I couldn't find Listener Setup in Hybrid Connection blade. I've tried manual setup of Hybrid Connection but it also shows same - Not Connected Status.

Comment: @Shalem You tried in the connection manager or on Azure portal? It also perhaps related to the Windows Server version, you could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987031/hybrid-connection-manager-doesnt-connect).

Comment: Accepted  - [Pre-Requisite] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections)  `This capability is only available on Windows Server 2012 or later. Because of that, HCM is not supported on anything earlier than Windows Server 2012.`

Comment: @JoyWang is HCM supported on Windows 10?

Comment: @Eniola I have tested HCM using Windows 10. It works.

Answer (score 41):

Just in case it might help someone else:

I was getting the same problem until I tried to restart the Windows Service "Azure Hybrid Connection Manager Service" AND reopened Hybrid Connection Manager (v.0.7.7)

Comment: Worked perfectly for me!

Comment: An hour of wasted time - thank you for this post.  This was what did the trick for me.

Comment: This was my fix, Thanks!!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks, still really helpful in 2023. It seems the service doesn't connect properly after the setup, so we must restart it.